# Shell script to know whether a filesystem is already mounted

Tags: shell, filesystems, mount

I have a tmpfs file system mounted on a particular directory. I want to write a shell script to check whether the tmpfs filesystem is already mounted on the directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the type of the filesystem.

```
$ stat -f -c '%T' /
xfs
$ stat -f -c '%T' /dev/shm
tmpfs
```

You could also check whether a directory is a mountpoint by comparing its device with its parent's.

```
$ stat -c '%D' /
901
$ stat -c '%D' /home
fe01
$ stat -c '%D' /home/$USER
fe01
```

Answer (score 53):

There's a tool specifically for this: mountpoint(1)

```
if mountpoint -q "$directory" ; then
    echo it is a mounted mountpoint
else
    echo it is not a mounted mountpoint
fi
```

And you don't even have to scrape strings to do it!

Note that I find this tool in Debian's initscripts package. How available it is elsewhere is not something I can comment on.

Comment: I see that mountpoint is part of the Gentoo Linux sys-apps/util-linux package along with more, mount, umount, dmesg, and a bunch of other system tools.

I would say this is the cleanest solution.

Comment: @cvolny: It turns out that `mountpoint` is part of util-linux (specifically the sys-utils part) and is probably available one way or another in most Linux distributions. It is, however, not part of GNU and not likely available on non-Linux systems.

Comment: Looks like it comes stock with RHEL 7.1 (err. ok, I have installed some stuff on here. So I can't be certain of that)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this, while hackish, should do the trick:

```
FS_TO_CHECK="/dev" # For example... change this to suit your needs.

if grep -F " $FS_TO_CHECK " /proc/mounts > /dev/null; then
    # Filesystem is mounted
else
    # Filesystem is not mounted
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but why not just use df and grep for the required path to the mountpoint? i.e. like this:

```
df /full/path | grep -q /full/path
```

grep returns true if mounted, false if not. So we just need to test it like this:

```
df /mnt/myUSBdisk | grep -q /mnt/myUSBdisk && echo "Mounted" || echo "Not mounted"
```

Easy peasy...

Comment: I decided to up-vote this one because although mountpoint would be easier for the question asked, this answer is more flexible. For example, some linux distros mount shared memory tmpfs at /tmp while others use /dev/shm or both. This answer makes it easy to realize you could tell if /tmp is shared memory or not the same way: `df /tmp | grep -q tmpfs && echo "Shared Memory" || echo "Not Shared Memory` Or, more to the point `df /tmp | grep -q tmpfs && tmp=/tmp || tmp=/dev/shm`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `df`, try `man df`.

```
df 'directory' | awk '{print $1, $6}'
```

will give you sth like:

```
Filesystem Mounted
/dev/sda5  'some_dir'
```

you can then add a check if the directory 'some_dir' is same as 'your_dir', and filesystem is same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Check /proc/mounts. If you grep on the filesystem name and the path you want it mounted (maybe even a specific line with all options included) you can tell if the filesystem is mounted.

```
if [ "`grep "tmpfs /lib/init/rw tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=755 0 0" /proc/mounts`" != "" ]
then
  echo Mounted.
else
  echo Not mounted.
fi
```

Comment: A virtual -1 for using backticks in a non-trivial location.

Comment: `if grep ...` - no need for brackets either.

Answer (score 0):

```
if mount -l -t tmpfs | grep "on $directory "
then
    echo "it's mounted"
fi
```

Answer (score -3):

mountpoint is much more elegant and is in sysvinit-tools CentOS 6+++

Comment: This low-quality answer duplicates an existing answer with more details from 2010